# When do we use conservation of momentum vs impulse momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

So, there is a projectile moving across at some initial velocity and sometime during its path it splits into two fragments with their respective angle from the horizontal.
I was told to apply the conservation of momentum to find the final velocities of the two fragments.

My problems are:

That I don't understand why shouldn't we use the impulse momentum principle instead since there is the weight acting in the negative $y$ direction initially while its travelling before it explodes.

So when coming to calculating for the $y$ components surely we should take into account the effect of the weight in that time interval before it explodes and use the impulse momentum principle instead?

And what does it mean by no "external forces" required in order to use conservation of momentum?

Comment: momentum is conserved; even in the case that you use impulses.

Comment: Do you think that the change in the momenta of the parts during explosion is due to gravity?

Comment: No it isnt due to gravity, but im confused now. When analysing the system when it  is in the intial state as one single object moving across surely the weight on the object is considered a external force no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to remind here:

1. Newton's law for a system of particles states that $\vec{F}_{\text{ext}} = \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}$, where $\vec{F}_{\text{ext}}$ is the total external force applied on the system and $\vec{p}$ is the total momentum.
2. A remarkable consequence of 1. is that you can write $\int \vec{F}_{\text{ext}} dt = \int d\vec{p}$ and, if you can assume that the total external force is constant in the time interval considered $\Delta t$, you get $\vec{F}_{\text{ext}}\Delta t = \Delta \vec{p}$, which is known as the "impulse theorem" (impulse being the force multiplied by time interval).

Now here comes your problem: BEFORE the projectile explodes, one certainly has to account for the external forces acting on it (typically the weight) in order to compute the projectile momentum at explosion time.
When it explodes, the explosion is due to **internal forces** and it is an instantaneous process, namely the time interval of the process is really short $\Delta t \to 0$.
This means that when you apply the impulse theorem, you have $\vec{F}_{\text{weight}} \Delta t = \Delta \vec{p}$ (you don't account for internal forces!), but now since $\Delta t \to 0$ and the weight force is **finite**, the left hand side is approximately 0 and as a consequence $\Delta \vec{p} = 0$: the total momentum is conserved and you can study the explosion of the projectile using conservation of momentum.

As a final remark let me give an example where this breaks down: if the projectile hits a wall with an inelastic collision, then the external force of the wall on the projectile $\vec{F}_{\text{wall}}$ is huge (say $\vec{F}_{\text{wall}} \to \infty$), so now the impulse $\vec{F}_{\text{wall}}\Delta t$ can be finite and there is a change of momentum for the projectile (makes sense since it goes from finite velocity to zero velocity)

Comment: Several misunderstands i just need you to clarify, i almost understand this. Before the project explodes as it moves across in space, why dont we account for the weight in order to find the projectile momentum at explosion time? Also from what i just read-are you trying to say you dont calculate the internal impulses during explosion interval but only the external impulses being the weight but since the time interval is so small you dont take it into account?

Comment: Well, actually you should account for the effect of weight before the explosion because weight affects the momentum of the projectile at the time of explosion, which is a crucial quantity. Also this is typically easy if there is no friction (just use kinematic laws of parabolic motion).  Regarding the second part, yes that's exactly what I was trying to convey :)

Answer (score 2):

In Newtonian physics, **total** momentum of a closed system is always conserved, no exceptions. However sometimes it is useful to use a different model of what is happening: the choice of what comprises the system is, up to certain extent, up to you.

In case of a splitting bullet in a gravitational field you need to consider three objects: the two fragments and the Earth. The momentum of the *entire* system is conserved: the fragments and the Earth will be attracted towards their centre of mass until they collide. This description is *complete* and you can predict all the future states of the system.

But since the Earth is many orders of magnitude more massive, its acceleration and total movement are extremely small in this example. For any practical purpose they are negligible and we can consider the Earth to be fixed. However this reference frame is no longer truly inertial. The Earth's gravity now must be treated as an external force and the total momentum of the two fragments in this reference frame is no longer conserved.

For the two fragments the acceleration due to this external force is the same -- as long as the field is homogeneous, which is not exactly true, but it is a reasonable approximation. Gravity pulls the entire new system (both fragments) in the same direction. The fragments now become separated due to an internal force, so within this reference frame momentum is conserved, even though as a whole it is accelerating. Therefore the velocities of the fragments, relative to the centre of mass, are inversely proportional to their masses,
$$\sum \vec{p} = m_1\vec{v_1} + m_2\vec{v_2} = \vec{0}.$$